# Barplots overlapping with blank subplot in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to make two subplots as a row in matplot lib.

Here is my code

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax1 = plt.bar(x="Topic", height='perc', data=df1)

ax2 = plt.bar(x="Topic", height='perc', data=df2)
```

What is happening is that the barplots overlap eachother and leave col1 empty.
How can I fix this[image: ?]

Comment: `ax1.bar`, `ax2.bar`....

Comment: omg thanks. Sorry. Would you be willing to explain why that works versus naming the entire plot ax1, ax2?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/matplotblog/posts/pyplot-vs-object-oriented-interface/